# Scala Why does this code compile?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

This is taken from week 6 from Coursera's functional programming in Scala course.

I am trying to wrap my head around the below code snippet. How is it possible to pass`charCode` to the string's `map` method although charcode doesn't have `(c: Char)` in it's parameter list?

```
/* define the map of numbers to letters */
val nmem = Map( '2' -> "ABC", '3' -> "DEF", '4' -> "GHI", '5' -> "JKL", '6' 
-> "MNO", '7' -> "PQRS", '8' -> "TUV", '9' -> "WXYZ")

 /* invert the map the get a map of letters to digits */
val charCode: Map[Char, Char] = for ((digit, str) <- nmem; ltr <- str) yield 
ltr -> digit

/* define a function that returns the numbers of a given word */
def wordCode(word: String): String = word.toUpperCase map charCode
```

I am used to passing functions to `map` like this:

```
  val s = "JAVA"
  val str = s map (lower)
  def lower(c: Char) = c.toLower
```

you can see that `lower` takes a char as a parameter

Moreover, Prof. Odersky mentioned that "The class Map[Key, Value] also extends the Function type Key => value so maps can be used everywhere functions can". Is this why the above code works? If yes how? I can't seem to find any documentation on this? What does it mean that "maps can be used everywhere functions can"?

Many Thanks,

Comment: You should first read https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html

Comment: This is called *inheritance* and / or *subtyping* (depending on which direction your question is coming from, it is not quite clear from your question) and is a standard feature of almost all object-oriented languages and some non-object-oriented ones as well. Are you familiar with some other languages? Which ones? Maybe we can help you better by showing analogies to those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It works because a `Map[A, B]` **implements** `Function1[A, B]`. The string's `map` method expects a function to transform each character into another character. That is, `Function1[Char, Char]`, which can be written as `Char => Char`.

When you call `map` with your `Map[Char, Char]`, the compiler will check that it is actually a `Char => Char`, as it implements `Function1[Char, Char]`.

### How is it implemented?

You can think of a `Map[A, B]` as a `PartialFunction[A, B]`. That is, a function that is implemented for a limited number of inputs. A `Map[A, B]` is just a mapping from a key of type `A` to a value of type `B`. So, your `A => B` function is implemented as: if map contains a key of type `A`, return its value of type `B`. If it doesn't exist, the partial function is not defined for that `A`.

### Hierarchy

The hierarchy that makes it possible is:

- `Map` implements `MapLike`
- `MapLike` implements `PartialFunction`
- `PartialFunction` implements `Function1`

Then, if you take a look into `MapLike`, you'll find `def isDefinedAt(key: K) = contains(key)`. This tells the partial function if a given value is defined or not. Then, it also implements `def apply(key: K): V`, required by `Function1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a map, as a special type of a partial function - partial means, that not necessarily all values are defined.

That is, a map `m = Map[S,T]` is also a function of type `S=>T`.

Let us take an example

```
scala> val includes = Map( 1 -> true, 2->false, 3-> false, 4->true)
includes: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Boolean] = Map(1 -> true, 2 -> false, 3 -> false, 4 -> true)

scala> (1 to 4).filter(includes)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4)
```

(If a value in the sequence was missing, you will get a runtime error).

So, in you question, you are passing the Map `charCode` into a map function, you ask why it does compile?

Well `String` in Scala is a type alias for Java's `string`. But in `Predef`, there is an implicit conversion from `String` to `StringWrapper` (low priority) - converts a string to a sequence of `Char`, and `StringOps` (higher priority) which injects the collection methods (like `map`). You can read more in the documentation for [strings](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/strings.html).

So, the Scala compiler treats your String as a sequence of `Char`s, and the map function converts each member using the supplied "function", ie the `charCode` map.

Answer (score 1):

[`Map[A, B]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/Map.html) extends [`PartialFunction[A, B]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/PartialFunction.html). Even though this is somewhat of a [red-herring](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle), every `PartialFunction[A, B]` is also a function `A => B` (it throws errors if it cannot find the key). The `map` method expects a function `A => B`, so everything fits together just nicely.

To summarize,

- `charCode` is a `Map[Char, Char]`
- therefore it extends `PartialFunction[Char, Char]`
- therefore it is also an ordinary function `Char => Char`
- it can be passed as an argument to `string.map`